# Lost texture on a linked object far from the origin file

Tags: texturing

I've modeled a file of a little city with many object linked into it. Some linked model lose its texture when far from the world origin (if I move the object near the origin the texture reappears)

i've tried to duplicate/relink o re-insert the object but the problem still remain

is there some settings that I have to modify to solve this little problem? why could it happens?

[image]

[image]

thank you very much for the help!

Comment: How far are we talking ?

Comment: 10 km more or less

Comment: How is the material setup in the base file ?

Comment: the material in the base file is quite simple, I don't know how to upload here some imagese but i uploaded them in this link. The strange thing is that, the same mesh, with the same materials in different files has the same behaviour in the "global file". in the we transfer link you can find the material setting and a tiny screen of the problem with the black rectangle - https://we.tl/t-jCQoeRBXky                                  thank you for the interest!